# Extract PDF group fields values from PDF document using IText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I need extract PDF fields values from PDF document using IText7. I am extracting string fields without any problems. But when I am trying extract fields values which are members of fields groups(for example toggle buttons), I have next problem.
Here my test code.

```
public class PdfTest
{
    // PDF document path
    public string PdfFilePath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    //PDF document copy path
    public string PdfFileCopyPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    private PdfDocument PdfDoc { get; set; }

    public PdfTest(string pdfFilePath)
    {
        Load(pdfFilePath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create copy of PDF document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pdfFilePath">PDF document path</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CreateCopyFile(string pdfFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Define directory for file copy
            string currentAssemblyPath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            string copyFileDirectory = string.Format("{0}\\Work\\Pdf", currentAssemblyPath);
            if (!IO.Directory.Exists(copyFileDirectory))
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(copyFileDirectory);

            // Copy file
            string copyFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", copyFileDirectory, IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfFilePath));

            if (IO.File.Exists(copyFilePath))
                IO.File.Delete(copyFilePath);

            IO.File.Copy(pdfFilePath, copyFilePath, true);

            PdfFileCopyPath = copyFilePath;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load PDF document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pdfFilePath">Pdf document path</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Load(string pdfFilePath)
    {
        bool result = true;
        try
        {
            PdfFilePath = pdfFilePath;

            // Create pdf file copy
            result = result & CreateCopyFile(PdfFilePath);

            //Initialize pdf document
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PdfFilePath);

            WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
            writerProperties.AddXmpMetadata().AddXmpMetadata().SetPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_6);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(PdfFileCopyPath, writerProperties);
            pdfWriter.SetCompressionLevel(0);

            PdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

            // Get pdf fields
            IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> pdfFields = GetPdfFields();

            //Extract toggle button fields
            IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> pdfToggleButtonFields = GetPdfToggleButtonFields(pdfFields);

            //Processing toggle buttons value
            dynamic fieldValue = null;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PdfFormField> field in pdfToggleButtonFields)
                fieldValue = (field.Value.GetValue() as PdfName).GetValue();

            return result;
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get PDF fields
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> GetPdfFields()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get form fields
            PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(PdfDoc, false);
            return pdfAcroForm.GetFormFields();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get toggle buttons
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> GetPdfToggleButtonFields(IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> pdfFields)
    {
        Dictionary<string, PdfFormField> pdfToggleButtonsFields = new Dictionary<string, PdfFormField>();

        try
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PdfFormField> field in pdfFields)
            {
                if ((field.Value is PdfButtonFormField) && ((field.Value as PdfButtonFormField).IsToggleOff()))
                    pdfToggleButtonsFields.Add(field.Key, field.Value);
            }

            return pdfToggleButtonsFields;

        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public bool ClosePdfFile()
    {
        try
        {
            PdfDoc.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

So, using this class, I trying to load data from simple PDF file which has only one toggle buttons group.
When I extracted toggle button fields using method **GetPdfToggleButtonFields**
and trying processing toggle button fields using construction
**fieldValue = (field.Value.GetValue() as PdfName).GetValue()**, I see that field value has not boolean value but has ordinal value. In my case this is “4” for all buttons. 
I suppose this is number of field which checked.
If toggle button fields have deliberate logical names – this Ok. I can analyze fields names and define: the group to which fields belong and ordinal fields numbers.
But, if fields have names like check1, check2, check 3 etc, I can’t define the group to which fields belong and ordinal fields numbers, so, I can’t correctly extract which button is checked.

Does anybody know what way allow correctly define logical value of field value in group when fields have not deliberate names?

Answer (score 1):

Objects related to the radio buttons can be logically divided into radio groups and radio buttons. Any radio button shall be added to the radio group to be logically connected with the other radio buttons in the same group. Both radio buttons and radio groups are `PdfButtonFormField` objects and you can get value from them using `GetValue` method. The value of each radio button is its identifier. Usually it is the index of the radio button but actually there can be any value. The value of the radio group is the identifier of checked radio button.
So using this information we can easily find out which radio button is currently checked. According to your code it seems that currently you are getting values of radio groups. In addition to this you need to traverse through the kids of each group and compare values of the kids with the one from the radio group